# STM32F078 I/O voltages

Tags: stm32, output, input, io

I'm working on a project right now and I'm building a schematic using the STM32F078. It's 1.8V. I know it has the analog/digital separate power supply of 3.6V max which on the data sheet is called DDIO2. Great, I get that. But in one section it says Max I/O out is DDIOx. While in my mind this makes me believe that the DDIO1 pins are all 1.8V max output and the DDIO2 pins are anywhere from 1.5 to 3.6V. But nowhere else in the data sheet does it mention 1.8V.

It specifically says in the pin description section that a pin labeled "TC" is standard 3.3V output. No mention anywhere else about 1.8V. And I can't find anything anywhere about internal output conversion within the chip. And almost every pin has the FT label except for those that are from the DDIO2 register. FT means they are 5V tolerant. OK, that's fine, but what about output? So, my question is, are the normal pins, those on DDIO1 that are labeled with TC or FT are they 1.8V output or 3.3V? My early assumption was that they were 1.8V but now I'm not sure because the only other output mentioned besides IO Vmax = Vcc +.04 is that standard I/O is 3.3V.

I'm using level shifting chips in this projects regardless, but I need to know what I'm shifting. Is it 1.8 or 3.3? Hopefully there is someone who knows this chip or other ST32 1.8V chips well enough to help. This is my first time using ST MCUs.

Comment: I didn't read the datasheet, but note often the I/O ports on a CPU can have a variable "VCC", which is dictated by a nearby power input pin.  Check the pin descriptions closely.  ST documentation is pretty good, the answer will be in the datasheet (somewhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assessment is mostly correct; most of the pins are indeed powered by VDDIO1 which is 1.8V (nominally). A selection of pins will be powered by VDDIO2, and you need to look at the package-pinout drawing in the datasheet to determine which one.
Here is an example for the UFBGA100 option, the upper right quadrant of pins is powered by VDDIO2

In my experience, the I/O structure designation (FT, FTf, etc.) are more about the input capabilities of the pins. STM32s are nice in that they have a lot of 5V tolerant pins for an otherwise low-voltage MCU, but the output characteristics can be a bit difficult to parse.

[image: STM32UFBGA IO Map]

Comment: Yes, I'm finding that out. The 5V tolerance is nice but I'm more concerned with the output. So, basically you're saying that DDIO1 outputs are 1.8V? That's my main concern.

Comment: Yes, the VDDIO1 pins are 1.8V on this stm32

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f078cb.pdf) is a link to the datasheet. It's best to link the datasheet and point out specific section numbers in your question.

The GPIO pins related to VDDIO1 switch between 0V and VDDIO1 when configured as outputs.

The GPIO pins related to VDDIO2 switch between 0V and VDDIO2 when configured as outputs.

You don't see references to specific voltages because the designer can choose to connect VDDIO2 (say) to 1.8V or 3V or 3.3V.  The USB won't necessarily work if VDDIO2 is less than 3.0V though.

---

When used as inputs, note that the internal pullups are connected to the related VDDIOx and if you intend on pulling or driving them much above that voltage (for example, driving a 1.8V input with 3.3V or 5V output ) you must disable internal pullups on such pins.

Comment: You see, that's my problem. I know which pins are DDVIO1 and DDVIO2 but I don't know that DDVIO1 is 1.8V or 3.3V by default. I have DDVIO2 connected with 3.3V and of course normal power to 1.8V. It says one time that outputs = DDIOx. DDIO2 is a separate power supply so it shouldn't have anything to do with DDIO1. I just assume that the data sheet would mention that DDIO1 is 1.8V if it runs from the main power supply and isn't upscaled.

Comment: I didn't mean to send that comment as it was unfinished. The data sheet shows• Power management
– Digital and I/O supply: VDD = 1.8 V ± 8%
– Analog supply: VDDA = VDD to 3.6 V
– Selected I/Os: VDDIO2 = 1.65 V to 3.6 V.   ok I get that. then it shows.                Pin type
S Supply pin
I Input-only pin
I/O Input / output pin
I/O structure
FT 5 V-tolerant I/O
FTf 5 V-tolerant I/O, FM+ capable
TTa 3.3 V-tolerant I/O directly connected to ADC
TC Standard 3.3 V I/O     most of the are either FT or TC. is says standard is 3.3V

Comment: VDDIO1 is connected to VDD and must be in the range of 1.66V to 1.94V for normal operation as per 3.5.1.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I assumed but the pin definitions section was making me second guess that.